# Trouble displaying database table in Listview

Tags: c#, database, oracle, listview

This is my first attempt at displaying my table information in a listview.  This is what I have put together so far and I cannot figure out why it is not working.  I am not getting any errors, the listview just remains blank when ran.

```
    listView1.Columns.Add("User", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Message", 382, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Date/Time", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    listView1.View = View.Details;

    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionInfo");
    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM MPCS.MEYER_BOARD WHERE BOARD_NAME = '" + cmbgroup.Text + "'", sqlConnection);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ada.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
        ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["EMPLOYEE_ID"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["POST_DATE"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["BOARD_NAME"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["MESSAGE_TEXT"].ToString());
        listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {listitem});
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and your `dt` _really_ has data? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. And use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and adapter.